# Multiprocessing in mxnet gpu support

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mxnet

I have a model trained by mxnet gpu support and i load this model on gpu. My problem is that when I multiprocess I get an invalid pointer error.how to do multiprocessing in mxnet gpu support?

Answer (score 2):

MXNet is written in C++ and natively uses parallelism when relevant. You should rarely need to explicitly multiprocess it manually. You can use parallelism for CPU-led data transport operations (`num_workers` in gluon `DataLoaders`), or when sending [inference payloads to an array of contexts such as here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/machine-learning/parallelizing-across-multiple-cpu-gpus-to-speed-up-deep-learning-inference-at-the-edge/), but when facing a single context (like your single GPU), I don't think that things will behave well as it seems that CUDA struggles with multiprocessing (see [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/4659) or [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-cuda-multiprocessing-with-single-gpu/7300/5))

What I recommend instead is to leverage native MXNet and CUDA parallelism as much as possible, via:

- the CPU: using a multiprocessed `DataLoader` (via `num_workers`) in training mode
- the GPU: sending batches to the GPU. In training mode that's pretty normal, in inference mode that means doing asynchrony to enqueue requests and send batches to
  the GPU. Modern DL servers such as [MMS](https://github.com/awslabs/mxnet-model-server) allows this.